# How to create a Facebook fitness:course object using Facebook SDK for .NET

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm writing a cycling app in C# for Windows Phone 8, using MVVM Light. I've successfully linked my app to Facebook using the latest version (6.6.0) of the Facebook SDK for .Net, and have posted a fitness:bikes common action using the following code:

```
private async void ExecuteShareButtonClicked()
{
    // Retrieve the Facebook session from Isolated Storage...
    var session = SessionStorage.Load();
    if (session == null)
        return;

    // Fire up the ProgressIndicator...
    ProgressIndicatorText = Resources.AppResources.FacebookUpdatingStatus;
    IsProgressIndicatorVisible = true;


    // Upload the course object to Facebook...
    string courseId = await CreateCourse(session);

    // Create the parameters for the fitness.bikes action
    if (courseId != string.Empty)
    {
        var bikesParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        bikesParams.Add("course", courseId);
        bikesParams.Add("fb:explicitly_shared", true);
        bikesParams.Add("start_time", RideModel.RideStartTime.ToString("o"));
        bikesParams.Add("end_time", RideModel.RideFinishTime.ToString("o"));
        if (MessageText != string.Empty)
            bikesParams.Add("message", MessageText);               

        var fbClient = new FacebookClient(session.AccessToken);

        // Upload to FB
        try
        {
            string postId = string.Empty;

            dynamic fbResult = await fbClient.PostTaskAsync("/me/fitness.bikes", bikesParams);
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbResult;      

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messageBoxService.Show(Resources.AppResources.FacebookErrorPostingStatus + ex.Message, Resources.AppResources.FacebookError);
        }
    }

    // Clear the ProgressIndicator
    ProgressIndicatorText = string.Empty;
    IsProgressIndicatorVisible = false;

    // Go back to the ride summary page...
    navigationService.GoBack();
}


private async Task<string> CreateCourse(FacebookSession session)
{
    string returnId = string.Empty;

    if (session != null)
    {
        var fbClient = new FacebookClient(session.AccessToken);

        // Convert the ride length from metres (as stored by the app) to kilometres or miles, depending upon the
        // value of MapUnits. MapUnits is an enum property which tells the programmer what units 
        // the user wants displaying. 

        var distValue = UnitConversion.ConvertDistance(RideModel.RideLength, MapUnits);
        string unitText = "m";

        switch (MapUnits) // MapUnits is an enum which tells the program if the user
        {
            case Measurement.Metric:
                unitText = "km";
                break;
            case Measurement.Imperial:
                unitText = "mi";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        var courseParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        courseParams.Add("fb:appId", App.FacebookAppId);
        courseParams.Add("og:title", RideModel.RideName);
        courseParams.Add("og:image", "http://marknotgeorge.co.uk/ApplicationIcon.png");
        courseParams.Add("fitness:distance:value", distValue);
        courseParams.Add("fitness:distance:units", unitText);
        courseParams.Add("fitness:duration:value", RideModel.RideTime.TotalSeconds);
        courseParams.Add("fitness:duration:units", "s");

        var objectParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        objectParams.Add("object", courseParams);

        try
        {
            dynamic fbResult = await fbClient.PostTaskAsync("/me/objects/fitness.course", objectParams);
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbResult;

            returnId = (string)result["id"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messageBoxService.Show(Resources.AppResources.FacebookErrorPostingStatus + ex.Message, Resources.AppResources.FacebookError);
        }

    }

    return returnId;
}
```

Now I wish to add advanced stuff such as split times and a map of the route using ActivityDataPoints. Here's the code I'm adding to CreateCourse to add the splits:

```
if (ShareSplits) // If the user has specified to upload split times, this is true.
{
    courseParams.Add("fitness:splits:unit", unitText);
    var splitParams = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    foreach (var item in RideModel.IntervalPoints)
    {
        // Interval times are stored every unit (kilometre or mile depending on user settings), 
        // plus a final one at the end of the ride. If the ride length is less than a unit, 
        // we only have one split to send, giving an inaccurate result. 
        if (item.Interval >= 1)
        {
            var param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            param.Add("fitness:splits:values:value", item.IntervalTime.TotalSeconds);
            param.Add("fitness:splits:values:units", "s");
            splitParams.Add(param);
        }
    }
    courseParams.Add("fitness:splits", splitParams);
}
```

As you can see, I've used a List<> to store the split values. Unfortunately, this fails with the following exception:

> (#100) Mixed Explicit Implicit Array Syntax: Object at URL '' of type 'fitness.course' is invalid because the property 'fitness:splits' of type 'fitness_splits' was specified with both explicit indexes mixed with implicit array syntax. Only one may be used at a time.

So how do I send fitness:splits and ActivityDataPoints? <s>Do I use an Array instead of a List?</s>

EDIT:
I changed the if (ShareSplits) code block to the following, which results in the same exception:

```
if (ShareSplits)
{
    Dictionary<string, object>[] splitParams;

    courseParams.Add("fitness:splits:unit", unitText);

    if (RideModel.IntervalPoints.Count > 1)
    {
        splitParams = new Dictionary<string, object>[(RideModel.IntervalPoints.Count - 1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < (RideModel.IntervalPoints.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            var param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            param.Add("fitness:splits:values:value", RideModel.IntervalPoints[i].IntervalTime.TotalSeconds);
            param.Add("fitness:splits:values:units", "s");
            splitParams[i] = param;
        }
        courseParams.Add("fitness:splits", splitParams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved it. I've used JsonArrays and JsonObjects, and altered the keys for the individual split and metrics points by removing the fitness:splits and fitness:metrics prefix.

The splits segment now looks like:

```
if (ShareSplits)
{
    courseParams.Add("fitness:splits:unit", unitText);

    if (RideModel.IntervalPoints.Count > 1)
    {
        JsonArray splitParams = new JsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < (RideModel.IntervalPoints.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            JsonObject splitPointParams = new JsonObject();
            splitPointParams.Add("values:value", RideModel.IntervalPoints[i].IntervalTime.TotalSeconds);
            splitPointParams.Add("values:units", "s");
            splitParams.Add(splitPointParams);                            
        }
        courseParams.Add("fitness:splits", splitParams);
    }
}
```